What is the status of the Book of the Wisdom of Solomon?
The Book of the Wisdom of Solomon is found in the Apocrypha and is used by a number of Christian groups. Notably, for our purposes, the Ramban quotes it in his introduction to his commentary on B'reishis. He says:

וְרָאִיתִי הַסֵּפֶר הַמְתֻרְגָּם הַנִּקְרָא חָכְמְתָא רַבְּתָא דִּשְׁלֹמֹה, וְכָתוּב בּוֹ: "וְלֹא מִמְּתֹם הֲוָת תּוֹלָדְתָא חֲדֵיתָא לְמֶלֶךְ אוֹ לְשַׁלִּיט דַּחֲדָיו מַעֲלָנָא דְּכָל בַּר נַשׁ לְעָלְמָא, וּמַפְּקָנָא שַׁוִּיאַת חֲדָיו מִיטוּל כֵּן צַלִּית וְאִיתְיְהִיבַת לִי רוּחָא דְּחָכְמְתָא, וְקָרֵית וְאָתֵית לִי רוּחָא דְּאַיְדַעְתָּא, צְבֵית בָּהּ יַתִּיר מִן שִׁבְטָא וְכָרְסְוָתָא". יֹאמַר, כִּי לֹא מִדָּבָר תִּהְיֶה תּוֹלֶדֶת מְיֻחֶדֶת לְמֶלֶךְ אוֹ לְשַׁלִּיט, אֶחָד הוּא בִּיאַת כָּל אִישׁ בָּעוֹלָם, וִיצִיאָה שָׁוָה לְכֻלָּם יַחַד, וּבַעֲבוּר כֵּן הִתְפַּלַּלְתִּי וְנָתַן לוֹ רוּחַ חָכְמָה, וְקָרָאתִי וּבָאָה לִי רוּחַ דַּעַת, בָּחַרְתִּי בָּהּ יוֹתֵר מִן הַשֵּׁבֶט וְהַכִּסֵּא.


Now I have seen the Aramaic translation of the book called The Great Wisdom of Solomon, and in it is written: “There is nothing new in the birth of a king or ruler; there is one entrance for all people into the world, and one exit alike. Therefore I have prayed, and the spirit of wisdom was given to me, and I have called out and the spirit of knowledge came to me; I chose it above scepter and throne.” (Charles B. Chavel translation)

What is the halachic/hashkafic status of this book?

Elsewhere Ramban himself addressed the question of why Wisdom of Solomon wasn't included in the Canon. In Drashat HaRamban al Divrei Kohelet (Schwartz ed., p. 9) he wrote:

"ומצינו עוד ספר שנקרא חכמתא רבתא דשלמה והוא בלשון תרגום חמור מאוד והגוים העתיקו[הו] מן הלשון ההוא ואני חושב שלא העתיקוהו אנשי חזקיהו מלך יהודה אלא ירד עמהם לבבל על פה ושם אמרוהו בלשונם כי היו חכמות ולא נאמר ברוח הקודש."
"And we find another book called The Great Wisdom of Solomon which is written in difficult Aramaic and the Christians have translated it from that language. I believe that this book was not arranged by the Men of Hezekiah, the king of Judah, but that it went with the Jews to Babylon orally and there they fixed it in their language, for it only contains sayings of wisdom and has not been written by inspiration." (translation from A. Marx, 'An Aramaic Fragment of the Wisdom of Solomon', JBL 40 (1921), p. 60).

So according to Ramban the book isn't canonical because it wasn't entirely written with Ruach Hakodesh and it was also written down much later than the Biblical Period, in Babylon. However, it does contain some real wisdom, which is why it can be referenced.
It should be noted that the book was mentioned in other Jewish works, such as Livnat Hasapir by Rabbi David b. Rabbi Yehudah Hachassid (e.g., here; and from there quoted by later authors such as Rabbi Avraham b. Eliezer Halevi, see e.g. here). Rabbi Azaryah dei Rossi thought that Wisdom of Solomon was originally written in Aramaic by King Shlomo without Ruach Hakodesh, to be sent to some far-off eastern (non-Jewish) king.
Interestingly, the Nodah be-Yehudah (Rabbi Yechezkel Landau) wrote in his haskamah to Naftali Hertz Wessely's commentary on Avot that though the Wisdom of Solomon was probably originally authored by King Shlomo, it had gone through so many translations and changes over the centuries that we no longer have it in its original form. Eventually Wessely went on to translate the book and print it, though notably he did not receive haskamot for that book.

By not "by inspiration", does this mean not by the word of God, but rather by his life experience and careful thought alone?

The Sanhedrin refused to include it in the Tanakh.  Several reasons are possible.  It was probably written in Greek, not Hebrew.  It came too late (first century).  It personified wisdom as the Egyptian "goddess" Isis.
